# Time and Date Apache Poi (if else statement not working)

Tags: apache, apache-poi

I'm working in my DTR project using java and apche poi excel file. The if else statement below doesn't work. If time is less than 12 it must be in cell 1 and if not it must be in cell 3. But it does not do what it must do. If time is >= 12 it still in cell 1. Please help. Thank you.

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
int month      = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
String IDnumF = (String) IDnum.getText();

FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Database\\"+IDnumF+".xls"));
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);;


Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(month);

Cell cell = null;

Date date = new Date();


int dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int day=dayOfMonth+7;




Row row = sheet1.getRow(day);


if(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY<12)//This code works
{

cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue(""+ calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

}


else {//this part doesn't..
   cell = row.createCell(3);
    cell.setCellValue(""+ calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
if(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY<12)
```

The value of `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` (note the big C) is a constant, used when fetching the hour part of a calendar value

Based on the rest of your code, I think what you want is:

```
if (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) <12)
```

That will fetch the hour of the day from your Calendar instance